# Append Price Without $ To Price Schema Content Attribute

Tags: javascript, dom, append

I'm trying to append 7.07 (without currently symbol) from: `<p class="regular-price">$7.07</p>` to the content attribute here: `<meta itemprop="price" content="7.07 Here" />`.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried and which framework/library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should achieve what you're looking to do with vanilla JavaScript:

```js
(function () {
  // Get references to the two elements
  var metaElement = document.querySelector('meta');
  var priceElement = document.querySelector('.regular-price');

  // Get the value of the `regular-price` element and remove the $ sign
  var priceValueModified = priceElement.innerHTML.replace('$', '');

  // Set the modified value as the attribute of the meta element
  metaElement.setAttribute('content', priceValueModified);
})();
```

```html
<meta itemprop="price" content="" />
<p class="regular-price">$7.07</p>
```